# Error unsupported pseudo: hover on jQuery

Tags: jquery

I tried to use an old jQuery script with jQuery version 3.2.1 but I have some issues, here is my code:

```
if (options.closeOnBlur) {
    el.on('blur', function (e) {
        if (!self.calendar.is(":hover"))
            self.hide(e);
    });
}
```

I know on new version `:hover` is deprecated but do you have any idea how to update it?

Comment: no the if is fine. it has issue with is(":hover")

Comment: Pleas read the whole thread.

Comment: @M.J did you read the whole of the linked duplicate?  It states how `.is(":hover")` no longer works and what to do to fix it, which is exactly what you're asking.